# Flag processed timestamp

Tags: support, flag-history

Is there a way to tell when a flag was processed? For example, an "aged away" flag requires that you wait 14 days after it was aged away before you can repeat the flagging action.

Comment: Yes, in your profile there's a link to your flag summary: activity page, top right box.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On [your flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3071284), hover over the flag status ("helpful", "aged away", etc.) and you'll see the date on which the flag was resolved.

[image]

Comment: This only gives the day ("2 days ago") and not the exact UTC time like all other such elements do. By design?

Comment: Reasonably precise after a couple of days, but no UTC time here because we're not displaying a relative time value outside of the hover.

Answer (score 13):

It would be nice if this information was clearly visible.

A slight adjustment to the CSS file would do the trick without having to do anything too crazy.

```
.flag-outcome:after{
    content: " - " attr(title);
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

As an alternative,  I wrote a userscript a while back that appends the time a flag was handled to the outcome.

[image: flag outcome time]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Flag Handled
// @author       ᴉʞuǝ
// @namespace    https://github.com/enki-code
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/users/flag-summary/*
// @exclude      *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude      *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://stackexchange.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';
$(function() {
    $(".flag-outcome").each(function() {
        $(this).append(" – " + $(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
```