# Comments disappeared on an answer

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

On [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566388/878701) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64564983) I had two comments and there was another from the answerer, but now these comments are missing.  Is there a history for the question? Can moderators remove other people's comments?

Comment: They were probably deleted by  a moderator. If the comments where thank you comments or something that isn't contributing to the post, then it was probably deleted.

Comment: As been suggested they were likely flagged by community users and handled by a moderator

Answer (score 19):

I happened across both the answer you're talking about, and this question. I raised three comment flags on comments on that answer about nine hours after the answer was posted:

[image: screenshot]

All three flags were marked helpful - so they were deleted. By [hovering over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316767/1364007) the "helpful" in my flag summary page, I saw that the first two were marked "helpful" in the same minute that I raised them (it's likely that they were [instantly deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/1364007)), and the last one 153 minutes later at 15:55.

From the [comment everywhere privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) page in the Help Centre:

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the
> following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, downvote (and provide or upvote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

I cannot remember the specifics of the comments that I flagged, but if I deemed them worthy of flagging (and the flags were marked helpful), it's extremely likely that they didn't add anything useful to the question or answer (i.e. were 'thanks'/'great answer', etc. comments).

To answer your questions

> Is there a history for the question?

Presumably you want to see the deleted comments - but [normal users do not have that ability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267887/1364007): "*only moderators (on their respective sites only), community managers and the SE developers can see deleted comments.*". I had a look on https://web.archive.org/ and there didn't appear to have been a capture of that page - before or after the comments were deleted.

> Can moderators remove other people's comments?

Yes - moderators can - and do remove others' comments: in 2019 [over six million comments were deleted by moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550/1364007).

Comment: BTW, they should probably eliminate the double negatives. They are confusing.

Comment: Okay, well that answers the mystery of where they went and why, but the remaining comment is useless without the conversation it was a part of.

Comment: It's also rather abrasive to see comments disappear without a reason.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Which remaining comment are you referring to?

Comment: @gregsdennis You have no reason to consider comments to be disappearing "without a reason" or in any case taking that to be "abrasive". Your question & comments aren't consistent with how the site works or with research into how the site works.

Comment: The second comment remained, but the others had been removed.

Comment: @philipxy regardless of how the site is designed, I felt removing the comment without any indication of why, whether overt or in history, confusing and sudden, i.e. abrasive.  This is how I felt. I'm just relaying my experience as a user.  Secondarily, I've been a user for years, and this is the first time this has happened.

Answer (score 4):

These are the original comments:

[image: Screenshot of deleted comments. You aren't missing anything, even if you can't see images.]

These comments do not add any useful information to the post. Going through them in order:

- The first comment is the asker leaving a "thank you" comment. These are regularly deleted. The correct way to say "thank you" is to upvote the answer (and award it a bounty, if you're especially thankful). Moderators might choose to keep a "thank you" comment if it adds some interesting or useful insight, but this one doesn't.
- The second comment is the answerer replying to the asker's "thank you" comment. *Obviously* the answer works in the answerer's environment... That isn't interesting or useful information.
- The third comment is... uh... *another* "thank you" comment from the asker.
- The fourth comment is... uh... *another* "you're welcome" comment from the answerer.

These are all just noise. So they were deleted.

Who flagged them and who deleted them is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: That is not very effectively redacted. We only have to look for users with a diamond after their name ...

Comment: When I looked the next day, all had been deleted except the second, which makes little sense out of the context of the rest.